# how to get a pointer of element's value in a double-linked list (go-lang)

Tags: pointers, go

I want to modify an element's value in a double-linked list, but I don't know how to get its pointer, because element's value is a nil interface defined by go-lang itself.
As far as I know is, I must do a type assertion before get element's value like:

```
val, ok := ele.Value.(TYPE)
if ok {
    // do something...
}
```

but if I just modify `val` it will be useless.
So any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: If you need a pointer, then store a pointer in the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pretty straight forward options. They're all going to involve type asserting because you're using `interface{}`

You can store it as a pointer and type assert:

```
var q interface{}
var i int
q = &i
*(q.(*int)) = 5
```

You can simply reassign it:

```
var q interface{}
q = 5
b := q.(int)
q = 2*b
```

I personally think reassigning it makes the most sense. If you're doing it in a function you probably need to return the new value. I'm sure there are other ways to change it around, but I think simple is best.

Of course in the real work some checking would be nice.

Comment: There are no other ways around it. You either store a pointer or a value.